# IF conditon with and or not working in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using an if statement in php.
What I want is -  if a user not enter a login id or usernamd+password,
then show an error message  - but the does not work,
Here is my code -

```
if($add_data['social_id']!="" || $add_data['username'] && $add_data['password']=="")
    {
        //login with social id code here
    }
elseif($add_data['username'] && $add_data['password']!="" || $add_data['social_id']=="")
    {
        //login with usernamd and password code here
    }
else
    {
        //please enter social id or username with password
    }
```

Comment: why not only 1 check `($add_data['social_id'] != ""){//social media}else{//normal}` just suggestion, in your condition you need to make to combine && as `((value1 && value2) || value3)`

Comment: When you use both && and || operators it is a good practise to use brackets for readibility. Otherwise it takes more time to understand the exact condition (and sometimes checking the documentation)

Comment: for suppose if all three input having values? then you will check social id only?

Answer (score 1):

Using `!=""` may return `true` if the variable has not been set, i.e. `null != ""`. You can overcome this by using `empty()`

```
if(!empty($add_data['social_id']))
{
    //login with social id code here
}
elseif(!empty($add_data['username']) && !empty($add_data['password']))
{
    //login with username and password code here
}
else
{
    //please enter social id or username with password
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$add_data['username'] && $add_data['password'] == ""` isn't doing what you are expecting. You can't factorise a condition this way.

Rather, use `$add_data['username'] == "" && $add_data['password'] == ""`

For more readibility, do the same for `$add_data['username'] && $add_data['password'] != ""` to be replaced by `$add_data['username'] != "" && $add_data['password'] != ""` (but this condition will work as expected, see below)

Doing `if ($var && $var2 == "")` will check if `$var` **is not false** and if `$var2` is equal to `""`

**Not false** (aka true) is something **different** than :

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

Every other value is considered `true`

Source : [Official documentatoin](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: without OP response, you and me cant do anything. :(

Answer (score -1):

you need to add an expression/value after each attribute in the if statement:

```
 if($add_data['social_id']!="" || $add_data['username'] != "" && $add_data['password']=="")
        {
            //login with social id code here
        }
    // add beside $add_data any expression
    elseif($add_data['username'] != ""  && $add_data['password']!="" || $add_data['social_id']=="")
        {
            //login with usernamd and password code here
        }
    else
        {
            //please enter social id or username with password
        }
```

Second, i did not understand what condition are you trying to put in there ?? if social id is not null and username or password aren't null ?? or all should be entered.

Please share this so i can send you the exact code.

Comment: i have following case

1) social id OR username+password is required 

2) if social id is there then no need for username+password

3) if username+password is there then no need for social id 

Thats it!

Comment: `$add_data['username'] != "" && $add_data['password']==""` **is equivalent to** `$add_data['username'] && $add_data['password']==""` (the original code)

Comment: so the code should be just like the one i've sent you above. you can skip the next elseif because it repeats the first condition ( Social id is required, or username and password).

Comment: @devterm the code you've provided doesn't change anything

Comment: ... And second condition shouldn't be skipped, because this is another case.